Algorithm for finding the minimum factorization of a tensor product expression
I originally asked a question on the Mathematica stack exchange on a similar topic here.
But it seems like my question actually extends beyond Mathematica. The issue is the following. Let $a,b,d$ be elements of some vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. I have some tensor product expression $a \otimes b$ that is non commutative, but is distributive over addition and linear and such: $$(c_1 a + c_2 b) \otimes d = c_1 a \otimes b + c_2 a \otimes d.$$
Given some long expression involving the sum of many tensor products. Something like:
$$a_1 \otimes b_1 + a_2 \otimes b_2 + a_1 \otimes d + a_2 \otimes d$$
I would like an algorithm that will find a factored expression with the minimum number of tensor products. For the above, that would be just two:
$$a_1 \otimes (b_1 + d) + a_2 \otimes (b_2 + d).$$
At the moment, my 'algorithm' is to:

Expand all tensor products so I do truly have a sum of single products
Recursively apply rules like $c_1 a\otimes b + c_2 a \otimes d \to a \otimes (c_1 b +
    c_2 d)$
Hope for the best.

This is working fine-ish, but is definitely not guaranteed to arrive at the factorization with the fewest terms. Because of the order that my program implements things it can get stuck on, for example:
$$a_1 \otimes b_1 + a_2 \otimes b_2 + (a_1+a_2) \otimes d$$
and doesn't realize this can be simplified further by instead grouping the $a$ terms together to get:
$$a_1 \otimes (b_1 + d) + a_2 \otimes (b_2 + d).$$
This is because I "group from the right" before I "group from the left" but regardless of which way I do it, there will be an analagous case to above where that runs into trouble.
This really feels like a problem that is common enough there should be a procedure for handling it. In fact, perhaps even one in Mathematica. I would be curious about a general thought as to a good algorithm, if I were to implement such a thing homebrew, or something specific to Mathematica.
In essence my problem is that my current algorithm is greedy, and not looking at the big picture

I think this could be solved with linear algebra and binary search.  I don't know whether there is a better algorithm.
Given $k$, I will describe an algorithm to determine whether it is possible to rewrite the expression using at most $k$ tensor products.  Then, you can use binary search on $k$ to find the smallest $k$ for which this is possible.
So, let's assume $k$ is fixed, and we want to know whether we can rewrite the expression to use at most $k$ tensor products.  Let $S \subset V$ denote the set of vectors that appear in the original expression.  Expand the original expression into the following form:
$$\sum_{s,t \in S} c_{s,t} \cdot (s \otimes t),$$
where the $c_{s,t} \in \mathbb{R}$ are known constants.  I assume that any factored expression will have the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\sum_{s \in S} d_{i,s} s\right) \otimes \left(\sum_{t \in S} d'_{i,t} t\right),$$
for some constants $d_{i,s},d'_{i,t} \in \mathbb{R}$.  I believe this is a fully general form of your factored expressions.  Now we want the original expression to be equal to the factored expression, i.e., we want to have
$$\sum_{s,t \in S} c_{s,t} \cdot (s \otimes t) = \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\sum_{s \in S} d_{i,s} s\right) \otimes \left(\sum_{t \in S} d'_{i,t} t\right).$$
This imposes some requirements on the constants $c_{s,t},d_{i,s},d'_{i,t}$.  Let's work out what the requirements are.  If we expand the factored expression, we find
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(\sum_{s \in S} d_{i,s} s\right) \otimes \left(\sum_{t \in S} d'_{i,t} t\right) =
\sum_{s,t \in S} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k d_{i,s} d'_{i,t}\right) (s \otimes t).$$
We want the above to be equal to the original expression, i.e., we want
$$\sum_{s,t \in S} c_{s,t} \cdot (s \otimes t) =
\sum_{s,t \in S} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k d_{i,s} d'_{i,t}\right) (s \otimes t).$$
This holds if for all $s,t \in S$, we have
$$c_{s,t} = \sum_{i=1}^k d_{i,s} d'_{i,t}.$$
Notice that this is a system of $|S|^2$ linear equations on the $2k|S|$ unknowns $d_{i,s},d'_{i,t}$.  Therefore, we can check whether there is any solution to this system of linear equations, e.g., using Gaussian elimination.
Finally, if there is a solution to this system of linear equations, then we have found a factored expression that is equivalent to the original expression and uses at most $k$ tensor products.  If there is no solution to this system of linear equations, then there is no factored expression of the listed form that uses at most $k$ tensor products and is equivalent to the original expression.  This gives us the claimed algorithm.

This is a truly wonderful answer. I am very grateful. The final step of solving for the $d$ and $d'$ matrices can be done easily using the singular value decomposition. If it is of interest to future readers I describe such an implementation in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946689/decomposing-multidimentional-matrices-into-contraction-of-2-dimentional-matrices, where I also ask if anyone knows of a way to generalize the use of the singular value decomposition to the factorization of tensor product expressions involving more than one tensor product symbol.
